# Can't download/update the internal test app version, and still gets the live version

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I did upload my test version to the internal test 4 days ago but every time I check the update of the internal test version app but it still gets the live version.

When tried to open the link of the internal test version, I got this [Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ugi1j.jpg)

and I tried all troubleshooting and the common ways to fix the problem.

**I don’t know why getting this issue, any help!**

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting caches of Google Play. It works most of the time.

Comment: I did try but still have the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the test version is older than the live one. Please check your version/number and codes

Comment: No, the internal test version/number is greater than the live version.